# tengo un problema con la alerta en formulario utilizando json

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

tengo un problema con un código, tengo un formulario en el cual tengo 3 campos (id, nombres y apellidos), la función es la siguiente: cuando el usuario digita el numero, mediante JavaScript se hace una consulta mysql y si encuentra el registro regresa los resultados y automáticamente rellena los otros dos inputs (nombre y dirección).
hasta acá todo bien pero cuando se realiza la consulta y este no devuelve ningún valor la alerta no se dispara, lo que necesito es cachar ese error, me mande una alerta y al mismo tiempo limpie los input.
Les dejo el código
**index.php**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prueba-ejemplo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm">
        <label>id:</label>
        <div><input type="text" id="id" name="id"></div>
        <br>
        <label>Nombres:</label>
        <div><input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" disabled></div>
        <br>
        <label>Apellidos:</label>
        <div><input type="text" id="apellido" name="apellido" disabled></div>
    </form>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("id").onchange = function() {
            alerta()
        };

        function alerta() {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.responseType = 'json';

            request.open("POST", "services.php");

            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                        document.getElementById("nombre").value = this.response.nombres;
                        document.getElementById("apellido").value = this.response.apellidos;
                }
            };
            var myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
            var formData = new FormData(myForm);

            request.send(formData);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**services.php**

```
<?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$RUT = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["id"]));


    $mysqli=new mysqli("localhost","root","","siscob"); //servidor, usuario de base de datos, contraseña del usuario, nombre de base de datos
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo 'Conexion Fallida : ', mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
    }

$sqlsi = "SELECT nombres, apellidos FROM altaalumnos WHERE idalumnos = '$RUT'";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sqlsi);
$dato = $resultado->fetch_assoc();

    $nombre = $dato['nombres'];
    $apellido = $dato['apellidos'];
    echo json_encode([
        'nombres'=>$nombre,
        'apellidos'=>$apellido
    ]);

    

} else {
    echo "Datos no encontrados";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si pusiste esto en tu petición: `request.responseType = 'json';` significa que **debes garantizar un JSON en todos los casos**, cosa que no haces cuando hay error o hay datos no encontrados.

Debes controlar el flujo de tu código PHP, creando un array, y emitirlo finalmente con `json_encode`.

Aprovecharé para blindar tu código usando consultas preparadas. No deberías nunca pasar a ejecución consultas que manejen datos externos. El uso de `htmlspecialchars()` en estos casos, pensando que protege de algo, es sólo una ilusión.

### PHP

```
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $RUT = $_POST["id"] ?? NULL;
    if ($RUT) {
        $RUT=trim($RUT);
        $mysqli=new mysqli("localhost","root","","siscob"); 
        if ($mysqli) {
            $sqlsi = "SELECT nombres, apellidos FROM altaalumnos WHERE idalumnos = ?";
            if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sqlsi)) {
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $RUT);
                $stmt->execute();
                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                $datos=array();
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $datos[] $row;
                }
                if($datos) {
                    $outPut=array('data'=>$datos);
                } else {
                    $outPut=array('error'=>'No se encontraron filas');
                }
            } else {
                    $outPut=array('error'=>'Error en la consulta SQL');
            }
        } else {
            $outPut=array('error'=>'Error en la conexión');
        }
    } else {
        $outPut=array('error'=>'No se envío un RUT válido para consultar');
    }
} else {
    $outPut=array('error'=>'Método no permitido');  
}
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode($outPut);
exit();
?>
```

### Javascript

En tu código del cliente, debes adaptar la función que lanza la petición y recibe la respuesta según la lógica seguida en el servidor.

Además, no sé por qué usas `this` para referirte a la respuesta, cuando petición está referida en la variable **`request`**.

Y, conviene que declares las referencias a los elementos una sola vez cuando usas `document.getElementById`.

El código debería quedar así:

```
//Declaramos fuera de la función la referencia a elementos
var elNombre=document.getElementById("nombre");
var elApellido=document.getElementById("apellido");
var myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");

function alerta() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.responseType = 'json';
    request.open("POST", "services.php");
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
            var json = JSON.parse(request.response);
            if(json.data) {
                elNombre.value = json.nombres;
                elApellido.value = json.apellidos;
            } else {
                alert(json.error);
                elNombre.value = "";
                elApellido.value ="";
            }
        }
    };
    var formData = new FormData(myForm);
    request.send(formData);
}
```